# How to display a word-document from google drive on website?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I would like to display some files from google drives embedded on a website.
I'm downloading the pdf's so they use the adobe plugin.

```
<object  data="https://docs.google.com/..." width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```

But I would like to display other files (word/excel,...) on the website too.
At the moment I'm using preview but I can't find a way to zoom in/out,download button,...

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/googleId/preview" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

I could also use /edit in stead of /preview but this gives the entire drive ui in an Iframe.

**Is there another way to display a drive file on a website?**

My application has all the drive Id's stored of the files it has to display. All the users who use the application have read access to the file!

Answer (score 2):

You can easily embed any document using Google Docs Viewer, like this:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.google.com%2Fuc%3Fexport%3Ddownload%26id%3D0BzEbtMoF6IXbRGE1MUtHYTI1Rkk&embedded=true" width="450" height="350"></iframe>
```

where `0BzEbtMoF6IXbRGE1MUtHYTI1Rkk` is the file ID.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to display these files would be to export them as PDF. For this, you can use the `exportLinks` of a file resource.

Google provide an example of how to fetch these export link in the [document about downloading files with the Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-downloads#downloading_google_documents).

Comment: Is it possible to make a exportLink by using the googlefile id?